# Passing pointer to unsigned string to bindings generated by kotlin cinterop

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm trying to use C-library with Kotlin-native C-interop, and I need to pass to a C-function some string. C-function has signature (omitting the details):

```
typedef unsigned char GByte;

void someFunFromC(GByte* data);
```

The same functions from Kotlin can be called like:

```
someFunctionFromC(data: kotlinx.cinterop.CValuesRef<libmylib.GByteVar /* = kotlinx.cinterop.UByteVarOf<libmylib.GByte /* = kotlin.UByte */> */>?)
```

So, how described in Kotlin documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mapping-strings-from-c.html) I tried to use it this way:

```
val kotlinString = "this is a Kotlin String"
someFunctionFromC(kotlinString.cstr)
```

and get:

```
Required : CValuesRef<GByteVar /* = UByteVarOf<GByte /* = UByte */> */>?
Found : CValues<ByteVar /* = ByteVarOf<Byte  /*>
```

It happened because I need to pass in C-function not
`char* cstring`
, but
`unsigned char* cstring`

Solution that I found to resolve it:

```
kotlinString.toUtf8().toUByteArray().usePinned { kString ->
    someFunctionFromC(kString.adressOf(0))
}
```

It work, but doesn’t look well. Maybe someone can suggest a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `kotlinString.cstr as? CValuesRef<GByteVar>`.

Comment: You was almost right. I tried `kotlinString.cstr as? CValuesRef<GByteVar>` and it failed inside C-library, but then I tried `kotlinString.cstr.ptr as? CValuesRef<GByteVar>` and it works!
Thank you for help